# iCalender gives error Mismatched 'BEGIN' and 'END' (BEGIN:VCALENDAR , END:VCALENDAR)

Tags: icalendar

my iCalender script gives me an error Mismatched 'BEGIN' and 'END' (BEGIN:VCALENDAR , END:VCALENDAR).
but it seems that it is correct.

below is my ical file script

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR 
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 14.0 MIMEDIR//EN 
VERSION:2.0 
METHOD:PUBLISH 
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE 
BEGIN:VEVENT 
CLASS:PUBLIC 
CREATED:20160617T000000Z 
DESCRIPTION:Overview
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160621T000000Z 
DTSTAMP:20160621T000000Z 
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160621T000000Z 
LOCATION:Westin Galleria Houston, Texas 
PRIORITY:5 
SEQUENCE:0 
SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:ABCD
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT UID:57639008a1a2d 
X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//E N">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html\; charset=iso-8859-1">
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="MS Exchange Server v ersion 14.03.0123.002">
<TITLE>ABCD</TI TLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
</BODY>
</HTML> 
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:FREE 
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-IMPORTANCE:1 
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:FALSE 
X-MS-OLK-AUTOFILLLOCATION:FALSE 
X-MS-OLK-CONFTYPE:0 
BEGIN:VALARM 
TRIGGER:-PT1080M 
ACTION:DISPLAY 
DESCRIPTION:Reminder 
END:VALARM 
END:VEVENT 
END:VCALENDAR
```

iCalender validation report

Errors

Mismatched 'BEGIN' and 'END' (BEGIN:VCALENDAR , END:VCALENDAR) near line # 65
Missing VCALENDAR object near line # 1Reference: RFC 5545 3.4 iCalendar Object

Please help,

Answer (score 1):

The X-ALT-DESC property value is not folded correctly.  Whenever a property value has multiple lines, each additional line must be prepended with one whitespace character, like so:

```
X-PROP:one
 two
 three
```

Also, your UID property is not on its own line.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I am a little late here, but it looks like you used the icalendar validator at http://icalendar.org/validator.html. I am the author of that validator and after researching the issue I found a bug with the validator related to your feed. The bug was incorrectly including the blank space after the word "VCALENDAR" to determine the mismatch condition. There was a space after the "BEGIN:VCALENDAR " but not after "END:VCALENDAR", resulting in the incorrect validation error. White space at the end of the line is not an error, so this has been corrected. And you can try re-validating your feed again to see the updated results.

Answer (score 0):

your `DTSTART`:

> DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160621T000000Z

and your `DTEND`:

> DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160621T000000Z

have the same values.

RFC5545 specifies

> The "DTEND" property for a "VEVENT" calendar component specifies the non-inclusive end of the event.

which means that your event is not-defined. if you wish the even to last one day, just remove the `DTEND`

Also you specify a `VALUE=DATE` but give a `DATE-TIME`. Either change the property to `VALUE=DATE-TIME` or change the value to be a date:

> DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160621

Answer (score 0):

It may also be related to a bug in Exchange 2016:

If you have recurrent events and modify one of the instances, Exchange 2016 delivers invalid iCal data, i.e., the `END:VCALENDAR` is missing.

See here for my bug report:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9952d9ea-6040-46b8-93d7-f163c09acd70/bug-in-ews-invalid-ical-format-if-recurrent-event-modified?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment